# Google auth2 asks for permission every time when asking for access to the app

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

Without changing my code or configuration, now google is asking users to grant permission every time when a user is trying to authenticate to my App. Even though the user already grated access and the scope didn't change.

I don't get any errors and the login works fine is just that now the google dialog asking for permissions appears every time.

To initialise google I use *gapi.auth2.init* with the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" as scope.
Also to request for access I use *auth2.grantOfflineAccess*.

I also checked in my Google account for Apps that have access and the application is registered successfully in there.

Anyone else has seen this issue? Or does know if google changed something in the way they handle permissions?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe I am seeing similar behavior... that the authentication flow has begun asking the user to grant the app permissions to the scopes every time they sign in.  Previously, it would only proceed from sign-in to grant permissions the first time the user signed into the app. I haven't changed the scopes requested nor the underlying code recently... but also hadn't used the app in awhile (months?)

I'm using the oAuth2 server-side authentication and grantOfflineAccess() outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) .
Given that there are no implementation details posted, i can't tell if the fix I found will apply to your situation.
The correction I found... so that the authentication only asks the user to grant the first time they sign into the app was to explicitly specify the "prompt" attribute when calling getOfflineAccess().

```
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance(); 

    auth2.grantOfflineAccess({
        prompt : 'select_account'
    }
    ).then(signInCallback);
```

Comment: Adding the "prompt" attribute did the trick. Thanks for your answer

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. You can also add login_hint: current_email after prompt (if you already know what current_email is) to pre-select the correct account.

Comment: This solution works in >99% of cases but there is an unknown corner case I am seeing which causes an InvalidGrantError

Comment: why not do prompt: none ?

Answer (score 2):

```
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline
```

Check Step 1 **prompt** parameter [image]